# OpenCV Mat to ffmpeg AVPicture conversion memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, ffmpeg, opencv3.0

I have next code:

```
void matToAvPicture(cv::Mat frame, AVPicture *picture)
{
    cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight));
    uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight)); // 3 bytes per pixel
    for(int i = 0; i < m_streamHeight; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&(buf[i * m_streamWidth * 3]), &(frame.data[i * frame.step]), m_streamWidth * 3);
    }
    AVPicture bgrPicture;
    avpicture_alloc(&bgrPicture, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight);
    avpicture_fill(&bgrPicture, buf, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight);
    sws_scale(rgbToYuvContext, (const uint8_t * const *)bgrPicture.data, bgrPicture.linesize, 0, m_streamHeight, picture->data, picture->linesize);
    avpicture_free(&bgrPicture);
//    free(buf);
}
```

But call of `avpicture_free(&bgrPicture)` doesn't free memory completely. If I commented line  `avpicture_fill(&bgrPicture, buf, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight);`  and uncommented line
`free(buf)`
memory leak doesn't appear.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight)); // 3 bytes per pixel
> avpicture_alloc(&bgrPicture, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight);
> avpicture_fill(&bgrPicture, buf, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, m_streamWidth, m_streamHeight);
> ```

That's doing the same thing twice. [avpicture_alloc](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#ga03b764a93c34d00e5a33a5ebb0b4a81b) allocates and fills the data array in a picture with a self-allocated buffer (free'ed with [avpicture_free](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gaf4ad71a7e39b54ee70f18cc451de956f)), and [avpicture_fill](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gac1b22e9b246cb8b0928cca8f5fa524d4) fills the data structure with some buffer that you control yourself (in your case: malloc/free manually). Use either malloc+[avpicture_fill](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gac1b22e9b246cb8b0928cca8f5fa524d4)+free, or use [avpicture_alloc](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#ga03b764a93c34d00e5a33a5ebb0b4a81b)+[avpicture_free](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gaf4ad71a7e39b54ee70f18cc451de956f). Don't use both.